# seperate the string array into two different string list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a string array

string[] lines=File.ReadAllLines(path);

The lines contains the below data

```
"A|3232|test"
"C|5544|test2"
"C|8884|test3"
"A|7777|test0"
"A|4343|test4"
```

I want to seperate the above array based on first letter "A" and "C". How to seperate the above lines and store in the bleow list strings.

```
List<string> aletterlines=
List<string> CletterLines=
```

Comment: What's you question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that help understand your question? Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Linq:

```
var lineGroups = lines.GroupBy(d => d[0]);
List<string> aLetters = lineGroups.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Key == 'A').ToList();
List<string> cLetters = lineGroups.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Key == 'C').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

List<string> aletterlines = new List<string>();
List<string> CletterLines = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in lines)
{
    string[] currentLine = item.Split('|');

    if (currentLine[0] == "A")
    {
        aletterlines.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        CletterLines.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that, you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) as others suggested or a simple foreach loop:

```
private void Example()
{
    string[] lines = {"A|3232|test",
                      "C|5544|test2",
                      "C|8884|test3",
                      "A|7777|test0",
                      "A|4343|test4"};

    List<string> aletterlines = new List<string>();
    List<string> CletterLines = new List<string>();

    foreach (string item in lines)
    {
        if (item.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            aletterlines.Add(item);
        }
        else if (item.StartsWith("C"))
        {
            CletterLines.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```